# how to get delays of a circuit under process corner in hspice?

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, simulation, inverter, delay

my circuit is composed of a chain of inverter (delay line), and i want to see how the delay of this chain of inverter behave in process corner? i want to know if the delay line will be still functionnal and the delay will be acceptable in process corner

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't that be left to the manufacturer who specced the chip? You inform your design tools which chip you are using, and your design tools make sure that your design will work on that chip.

Comment: thank you for your response, i act as a designer and the circuit is not yet manufactured, i only have corner specification of pmos and nmos transistor and i don't know how to perform worst case analysis of my circuit in hspice.

Answer (score 1):

The models from the fab will have information on the corners in the .inc file, such as the nfet.inc  You then just have to select the monte carlo option in the HSPICE configuration.  You should have a few options: fs, tt, etc.

You basically just need to read the [manual](http://www.ece.rochester.edu/courses/ECE222/hspice/hspice_simanal.pdf).   Page 486 will show you what each model means, and then you can setup the run from there.

Comment: thank you for the answer, if i understand correctly i should add my parameters setting to the library file(setting parameters to their 3sigma value)? because when checking the library file, i found the definition of parameters for each of the process corner, but i do not know how to add this in my spi file (which contain the description of my circuit ) for the worst case analysis?

Comment: It would look something like this:  .lib 'l355v.l' FF , where FF is the model selection.